# Trouble in installing Magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2.3, installation, localhost

I tried installing Magento 2.3.2 in windows using xampp. Initially, I tried it via localhost/Magento root_folder/setup but in the installing step it stuck at 0%. So I have dropped db and removed etc/env and now tried installing via below command

```
bin/magento setup:install
```

Now, in the database all the tables are created but when I check the site via frontend it still redirects to localhost/Magento root_folder/setup.

Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the below command in your MySQL instance and then flushing the Magento cache:

```
Update core_config_date set value = 'http://localhost/Magento root_folder/' 
Where path like '%base_url'
```

Answer (score 0):

Run All Below Command

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade 
php bin/magento cache:clean 
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f 
php bin/magento indexer:reindex 
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Then check in private window.